# How to increase speed removing leading zeros

Tags: r

I have this piece of code to remove leading zeros in strings and I would like to know if it is possible to increase its speed

```
rmleadingzeros <- function(x){
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="00",replacement="0"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="01",replacement="1"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="02",replacement="2"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="03",replacement="3"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="04",replacement="4"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="05",replacement="5"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="06",replacement="6"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="07",replacement="7"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="08",replacement="8"))
x <- as.numeric(sapply(x,gsub,pattern="09",replacement="9"))
return(x)
}

datainOKdate$mo <- rmleadingzeros(datainOKdate$mo)
```

Many thanks

Comment: er... `f <- function(x) gsub( "^0+" , "" , x )`. However, will you be dealing with decimal character strings?

Comment: your rmleadingzeros functions seems to remove more than just leading zeros -- eg rmleadingzeros("001001") returns 11

Comment: I have never used regex with R before but I assume you could just replace a zero at the beginning with an empty string. And you could also replace 0 to n zeros by using the correct regex. (your example only replaces one leading 0 if I am correct)

Comment: Have you tried just `as.numeric(x)`?

Comment: you can also do as.character(as.numeric(vector.of.strings))

Comment: @Henrik yup. That's about right! You should give that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x <- paste0(0, 1:9)
x
# [1] "01" "02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09"

as.numeric(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

**Update following comment**
If `x` is a factor we have to be more careful. See "Warning" section in `?factor`

```
x <- as.factor(paste0(0, c(1, 11, 22, 3)))
x 
# [1] 01  011 022 03 
# Levels: 01 011 022 03

as.numeric(x)
# [1] 1 2 3 4
# not what we want

# This is the way according to ?factor
as.numeric(as.character(x))
# [1]  1 11 22  3

as.numeric(levels(x))[x]
# [1]  1 11 22  3
```

Comment: The problem was that I was starting from factors and not characters, so as.numeric wasn't working

Comment: OK. Please read the "Warning" section in `?factor` on how to safely convert factor to original numeric values.

Comment: @user3036416, I updated the answer according to your comment.